# Смена цвета ячеека dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, color

```
List<CriticalError> troubles = new List<CriticalError>(); // связывается с таблицей
this.dataGridView.DataSource = 
troubles.GetRange(0,troubles.Count); //чтобы не выдавало ошибку индекс -1
for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
   if (Convert.ToBoolean(this.dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["Reaction"].Value) == false) // если CheckBox == false , тогда красим в красный
   {
       this.dataGridView.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
   }
}
```

Проблема в том , что в цикле `dataGridView.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor` принимает желаемый цвет, а после выхода с цикла все по дефолту. Подскажите, пожалуйста , где ошибка

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (Convert.ToBoolean(this.dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["Reaction"].Value) == false)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <this.dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells.Count - 1; j++)
        {
             this.dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так не работает для ячейки, нужно указывать конкретную ячейку в `Cells`, не только строку. Вот так поменяет строку в красный:

```
this.dataGridView.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

В Вашем случае, для окраски ячейки писать так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
   if (Convert.ToBoolean(this.dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["Reaction"].Value) == false)
   {
       this.dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["Reaction"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
   }
}
```

Чтобы смена цвета работала для `DataSource` необходимо повесть метод на событие `DataBindingComplete`, получится такой код:

```
private void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(
    object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Reaction"].Value) == false)
        {
            this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Reaction"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: переделал , так не работает, к сожалению
Мне нужно не одну ячейку красить , а всю строку

Comment: @MikhailZnak, значит условие не срабатывает. Пример проверен, работает

Comment: точку остоновы ставлю, в цикл заходит.
 Дело в том, что и то, как я сначала делал, работает , но в том случае, если я буду вручную добавлять строки и колонки, а  не через `DataSource`

Comment: @MikhailZnak, понял. В каком месте лежит этот код? Не в конструкторе?

Comment: у меня в самом конце конструктора запускается `Task` на обновление таблицы с промежутком в 10 сек. 
если важно, то все отображается хорошо, кроме цвета

Comment: @MikhailZnak, посмотрите обновление ответа

Comment: Спасибо ! все как надо

Comment: @MikhailZnak, Your welcome )